# Scroll UITextView to specific text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

i have a uitextview with large texts and above i have a search field. Anything searched, i would love the uitextview to scroll to that specific text and hightlight. And i need to make sure that the uitextview scrolls in such a way that the searched text stays in the first line

I populated the textview with attributed text with some attributes. What i tried is get the text before the target text and tried to get the size of it adding the exact attributes i added on textview text at the beginning.

made a CGPoint using that height and set the contentOffset of the uitextview. But the textview scrolled no where near the  target text. Maybe my approach is wrong as i dont have the width of the textview when setting attributes

My code is :

```
func goToBla() {
        if let string = ayatTextView.text {

            if let range = string.range(of: tazweedAyahas[8].text) {
                let firstPart = string[string.startIndex..<range.lowerBound]
                print("before \(tazweedAyahas[5].text) : ")
                print(firstPart)


                if let otherStr = firstPart as? NSString {
                    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
                    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

                    let size = otherStr.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
                                                   NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "me_quran", size: 30)
                        ])

                    let point = CGPoint(x: 0, y: size.height)
                    ayatTextView.setContentOffset(point, animated: true)
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your approach is much more complicated than it needs to be. Use the `scrollRangeToVisible` method of `UITextView`.

```
func goToBla() {
    if let string = ayatTextView.text, let range = string.localizedStandardRange(of: tazweedAyahas[8].text) {
        let viewRange = NSRange(range, in: string)
        ayatTextView.selectedRange = viewRange // optional
        ayatTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(viewRange)
    }
}
```

Note the following:

1. Use `localizedStandardRange` when searching if you want to ignore diacritics and case, and you want other locale specific search features.
2. Call `selectedRange` if you want the matching text selected.

If you want to get the selected range at the top, try something like this instead of calling `scrollRangeToVisible`:

```
let rect = ayatTextView.layoutManager.boundingRect(forGlyphRange: viewRange, in: ayatTextView.textContainer)
ayatTextView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.origin.y)
```

Comment: this approach works nicely. There is only one problem i am facing with it. uitextview scrolls and show the searched text and thats great. But i need to make sure that the uitextview scrolls in such a way that the searched text stays in the first line

Comment: It would have been helpful if that important detail was in your question.